# Why can't I read a component's state inside a DropEvent callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble understanding why I cannot read a component's state variable inside of a marker drop callback function on a map component.

Inside my component I initialise this state as null

```
const [testBool, setTestBool] = useState(null);
```

I declared a function to handle the state change

```
const testFunc = () => {
  setTestBool(true);
}
```

and the callback function that gets executed after a marker has been dropped on a map component

```
const handleMarkerDrop = e => {
  console.log('test bool', testBool);
}
```

Inside my render I put a button to execute testFunc and the map component

```
<button onClick={testFunc}>set to true</button>
  <SomeKindOfMapComponent
     // other props here
     onMarkerDrop={handleMarkerDrop} />
```

When I click the button the state gets updated (I can console log it as true before the return) but when I perform a marker drop and the handleMarkerDrop function gets executed, testBool is read as null

I also tried workarounds like passing the prop as `{e => handleMarkerDrop(e, testBool)}` but still doesn't work as I would expect

Comment: I can also read it inside the return (render) as `<button onClick={() => alert(testBool)}>read state</button>` but not on the handleMarkerDrop

Comment: It would be necessary to see some surrounding code to answer this question. But probably the handleMarkerDrop function captures testBool (as a closure), and has to be rebuilt when testBool changes.